# Rebase private history moving bunch of changes where they logically belong to

Tags: git, rebase

Quite often, I make a bunch of commits and review the files later, but before pushing them. This usually leads to a bunch of minor changes like reduced visibility, improved naming, etc. Such changes usually can and should be included into the last commit changing the corresponding file, assuming this commit haven't yet been pushed.

I wonder, if there's an easy way to automate this process, i.e.,

- for each dirty file, find the last commit modifying it
- if this commit lies in a range (e.g., `master..origin/master`)
- then amend this commit with this change

Comment: Sounds like recently [promoted](https://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2018/11/05/absorbing-commit-changes-in-mercurial-4.8/) `hg absorb`. Quick googling shows there is at least one [git port](https://github.com/tummychow/git-absorb), but I have not tried it

Comment: @max630 My idea was actually simpler, but `hg absorb` sounds much smarter. I haven't tried the `git` port yet either, but I will when I get some spare time.